# Using Google People Api to get user Google Plus cover picture

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, google-people-api

I'm using Google Sign In to get basic user's profile data but I need to get the user's cover photo from Google Plus. I know that Google Plus is deprecated so I read about Google People Api. The problem is that when I try to implement the example exposed [here](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started), the following code's lines could not be resolved because the package does not exists,

```
People peopleService = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .build();
```

The doc's example use

```
import com.google.api.services.people.People;
```

but if I try to import that package, it doesn't exists. I only can import

```
com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleService.People
```

and with that package, the Builder method doesn't exists.

Here is my Gradle file,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev91-1.21.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.17.0-rc' exclude module: 'httpclient'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc' exclude module: 'httpclient'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.17.0-rc' exclude module: 'httpclient'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.21.0'
```

And here, I show you how I try to implement Google People Api,

```
public static People setUp(Context context, String serverAuthCode) throws IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    // Redirect URL for web based applications.
    // Can be empty too.
    String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    // STEP 1
    GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
            httpTransport,
            jsonFactory,
            context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id),
            context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id),
            serverAuthCode,
            redirectUrl).execute();

    // STEP 2
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setClientSecrets(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id), context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .build();

    credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

    // STEP 3
    return new com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleService.People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: The [Google+ People.get API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people) is still the method to get Google+ profile information. The deprecated Google+ People.list method that is deprecated was for getting a list friends/followers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the example is wrong, you need to use [PeopleService.Builder](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/people/v1/PeopleService.Builder.html).